# JavaScript: Escaping double quotes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

How can I prevent the `images[i].title` below from breaking the HTML if it contains double quotes?

```
for (i=0; i<=images.length-1; i++) {
    gallery += '<img width="250" height="250" src="' +  images[i].src + '" title="' + images[i].title + '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method to escape the double quotes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    gallery += '<img width="250" height="250" src="' + images[i].src +
               '" title="' + images[i].title.replace(/\"/g, '\\"') + '" />';
}
```

The result will be a valid JavaScript string, but it won't work as HTML markup, because the HTML parser doesn't understand backslash escapes. You'll either have to replace double quote characters with single quotes in your image title:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    gallery += '<img width="250" height="250" src="' + images[i].src +
               '" title="' + images[i].title.replace(/\"/g, "'") + '" />';
}
```

Or invert the quote types in your markup:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    gallery += "<img width='250' height='250' src='" + images[i].src +
               "' title='" + images[i].title + "' />";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to double escape it, as it is in single quotes.  Plus, `replace` will only take care of the first quote unless you do `/\"/g`.

Comment: @Jeff, you're right about `replace()`, thanks :) But what do you mean by `double escape`?

Comment: You have `'\\"'`, but you really want `'\"'`.   It's a single-quoted literal string, so you don't need to escape anything, including the slash.

Comment: And I just realized this is wrong, because escaping does not work in html this way.

Comment: @Jeff, indeed, single-quoted strings are not special in Javascript: `'\"'` is the same as `"\""`, i.e. the double quote character `"`. But `/bin/bash` does what you want :)

Comment: Oh, you are correct.  I am so used to Perl's literal string usage, I forget that Javascript doesn't differentiate.  But, you can't escape in an html attribute anyway, so the point it moot.

Comment: Frédéric and Jeff, thank you both for your responses. I've accepted this answer because of the follow-ups and choices provided.

Answer (score 15):

Since no one seems to have exactly the right answer in my opinion:

```
for (i=0; i<=images.length-1; i++) {
    gallery += '<img width="250" height="250" src="' +  images[i].src +
               '" title="' + images[i].title.replace(/\"/g,'&quot;') + '" />';
}
```

This replaces **all** quotes, and you end up with double quotes, and they are represented in an HTML format that is valid.

Comment: This is the correct answer because you are outputting an HTML attribute, so you have to apply HTML attribute encoding for quotes (&quot; for ") not JavaScript encoding for them.

Answer (score 2):

```
var_name.replace(/\"/gi, '%22');
```

That's the one you're looking for. Even if your colors look "off" in Visual Studio.

`\` escapes the following quote.

`gi` does a replace for all occurrences.

Comment: This is only true for attributes which contains url, normally you are suppose to HTML encode the value of the attribute, not url encode them.

Answer (score 1):

You can call replace on your title string:

```
for ( i=0;i<=images.length-1;i++ ){
    gallery += '<img width="250" height="250" src="' +  images[i].src + '" title="' + images[i].title.replace('"',"'") + '" />';
}
```